# A Russian word describing radio and television

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

I know there is a word in Russian that describes all the print media — *пресса*. Is there any word in Russian that would describe only radio and television?

Comment: Is there such a term in English?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan - Not that I know of.

Comment: In English you can say "broadcast media". It's a bit clunky but people do use it - it gets about 8.5 million Google hits. A bit less clunky but less precise is "broadcasting", which is much more common.

Comment: Есть ли слово в русском языке, чтобы описать только радио и телевидение? Я могу ответить на этот вопрос с точки зрения носителя русского языка с тонким
слухом на слова. Термин "телерадиовещание" - верный ответ на заданный вопрос. Но это слово из официального языка (газетного, телевизионного), и даже в газетах, на телевидении и на радио оно употребляется очень редко... Это правильный, редко употребляемый термин. Вызвавшее такое бурное одобрение слово "эфир" в разговорной речи и в СМИ практически не употребляется. Это, скорее, сугубо профессиональное слово работников телевидения и радио, и кроме

Comment: @МатвейДёмин - "**Вызвавшее такое бурное одобрение слово "эфир" в разговорной речи и в СМИ практически не употребляется**" - Doesn't sound true to me.

Comment: Никто в России не называет словом "эфир" телевидение и радио (ни вместе, ни по отдельности). Никто не употребляет слово "зфир" для обозначения теле- или радиопередач (говорят "я смотрел вчера вечером по TV", но НЕ говорят "я смотрел в  вечернем эфире"). Это профессиональное слово работников TV и радио. У них есть словосочетания "утренний, дневной, вечерний эфир", "работать в прямом эфире", "эфирное время", "мы уходим из эфира" и т.п. Но это уже практически профессиональный жаргон. Ещё только журналисты изредка используют слово "эфир" в своих статьях. Слово "эфир" - мало употребляемое.

Comment: @МатвейДёмин - "**Это профессиональное слово работников TV и радио ... Слово "эфир" - мало употребляемое**" - And yet you can hear it on TV and on the radio quite often. Way more often than _телерадиовещание_.

Comment: Услышать по телевизору и радио можно нередко. Но - только там).

Comment: И это не делает слово "эфир" верным ответом на поставленный вопрос. Слово "телерадиовещание" вообще нигде нельзя услышать, но оно-то как раз и является верным ответом на вопрос. Мы же здесь отвечаем на вопрос, а не говорим о частоте употребления слов.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's also the noun *эфир* (lit. ‘ether’), which can be used to refer to both radio and TV (including Internet video streams). [*В эфире*](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%22%E2+%FD%F4%E8%F0%E5%22) means ‘on air’, *в прямом эфире* is for ‘live on air’, and you can say something like:

> Его жестоко ругали и в прессе, и в эфире
>
> ‘He has been harshly criticized in the press as well as on air’

Answer (score 9):

I don't know any word or phrase that specifically describes radio and television. The more general term for all the media is

> средства массовой информации (or simply СМИ, pronounsed /smi/ rather than /es-em-i/)

Things that pertain to radio and TV are usually called using something like "радио и телевидение" . E.g.

> Музей телевидения и радио
>
> Институт телевидения и радиовещания.

The closest thing that I can think of is broadcast, which would be translated to Russian as

> вещ**а**ние

Or, if you want to be more specific about it:

> теле- и радиовещание.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is such a word. It's [***телерадиовещание***](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&stable=0&redirect=no).

Answer (score 2):

A widespread term — ***электронные СМИ***, which includes TV, radio and internet media.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor and/or repetitive answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed. In case it gets deleted, you can still edit it; if you improve it and wish for it to get undeleted, please use **flag for moderator attention**, then choose **custom** and shortly explain the situation.

Answer (score 1):

МАСС-МЕДИА неизм.; ж.
Средства массовой информации (пресса, телевидение, радио и т.п.). Западная, отечественная м.

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE.  Please avoid repeating existing answers unless you are providing more information.  Also, please answer in English if the original question was asked in English.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Poor answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "эфирные медиа" or "эфирные сми" but it is not a widespread phrase.

Comment: Interesting... I never heard either of the two phrases, however individually each word is commonly known.